# How to handle S3 Internal Server Errors when rdd.write.csv on Amazon EMR?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-emr

I have a pyspark Amazon Elastic Map Reduce (EMR) application that is writing to S3 using the `rdd.write.csv` method. This works 99.999% of the time. Unfortunately 0.001% of the time we get an internal S3 error during the write.

The error happens on the EMR worker nodes. We cannot catch this with a Python try/catch statement.

Here is an example of the error message we receive:

```
Caused by: com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Internal Server Error 
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 500; Error Code: 500 Internal Server Error; 
Request ID: F0AFDAB32ADEF5EC; S3 Extended Request ID: aHJpZ0drMEZOREl5b0lUQWI2YkRKWFZWT2hCbnhFUmlDeVlLV2JFOFlVM2ljU1ZINmxFdDVZMTVweEMxNWQK4=), 
S3 Extended Request ID: aHJpZ0drMEZOREl5b0lUQWI2YkRKWFZWT2hCbnhFUmlDeVlLV2JFOFlVM2ljU1ZINmxFdDVZMTVweEMxNWQK4=
```

I'm not seeing any obvious solution other than writing to HDFS and then using a subprocess to copy the file from HDFS to S3.  That might still crash, but at least I can retry it without killing my `pyspark` program.

We also also seeing occasional errors in a `aws s3 cp --recursive s3://bucket/prefix/file local/file`. Again, the failure rate is around 0.001%.

Amazon says we should retry. The problem is, there's no way to retry the `rdd.write.csv` when the errors happen on the worker nodes. Or is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `fs.s3.maxRetries` defaults to 4:

```
$ hdfs getconf -confKey fs.s3.maxRetries
4
$
```

Increasing this to a higher number will increase the number of retries.